# What is the unit in returned by MySQL GLength method?

Tags: mysql, geospatial

I want to get the length in meters between 2 points in the surface of the Earth. But the `GLength` method returns an unexpected value

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/geometry-property-functions.html#function_glength

```
SELECT GLength(GeomFromText(
   'LINESTRING(-67.8246 -10.0073,-67.8236 -10.0082)', 4326))
```

actual result

```
0.00134536240471071
```

expected value in meters:

```
147
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't found a source, but I was playing with this method and I concluded that the result is given in the same unit used in the WKT.

And the distance is calculated in planar coordinates. The SRID is not taken into account.

Comment: i am sorry i am new to this, but can we convert this 0.00134536240471071 to expected result 147 as per question?

Answer (score 4):

I guess it's about 3 years too late for the OP, but I happened across this question while researching a similar topic, so here's my tuppence worth.

According to [www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) there are 3 ways of calculating distance across the Earth's surface, these being, from easiest to most complex (and thus from least to most accurate): Equirectangular Approximation, Spherical Law of Cosines and the Haversine Formula. The site also provides JavaScript. This is the function for Equirectangular approximation:

```
function _lineDistanceC(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {   
    var R = 6371; // km
    lat1 = lat1.toRad();
    lon1 = lon1.toRad();
    lat2 = lat2.toRad();
    lon2 = lon2.toRad();
    var x = (lon2-lon1) * Math.cos((lat1+lat2)/2);
    var y = (lat2-lat1);
    return Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y) * R;
}
```

This is my attempt at a SQL equivalent:

```
drop function if exists lineDistanceC;
delimiter //
CREATE FUNCTION lineDistanceC (la1 DOUBLE, lo1 DOUBLE, la2 DOUBLE, lo2 DOUBLE) RETURNS DOUBLE 
BEGIN 
    SET @r = 6371;
    SET @lat1 = RADIANS(la1);
    SET @lon1 = RADIANS(lo1);
    SET @lat2 = RADIANS(la2);
    SET @lon2 = RADIANS(lo2);
    SET @x = (@lon2-@lon1) * COS((@lat1+@lat2)/2);
    SET @y = (@lat2 - @lat1);
    RETURN (SQRT((@x*@x) + (@y*@y)) * @r);
END
//
delimiter ;
```

I have no idea how accurate this formula is, but the site seems very credible and definitely worth a visit for more detail. Using the coordinates in the question, the results (in kilometres) from the above JavaScript and SQL are 0.14834420231840376 and 0.1483442023182845, which makes them the same to a fraction of a millimetre, but not, curiously, the 147 metres that the OP was expecting. Enjoy.

Comment: This is the most accurate SQL function I've found to determine distance between geo locations. I'm simply using the X(fieldname), Y(fieldname) on my POINT data field to send the lat/lon to the function.

Answer (score 3):

1 degree (your input unit) ~= 69 miles.  So, if you multiply your results by 69 miles and then convert to meters, you get roughly 149 meters.  Not exactly what you expected but pretty close.  Of course I don't think that accurately reproduces the spherical nature of the globe, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: No it doesn't reproduce the spherical nature of the globe. If you convert distances near the poles by this method you will get unacceptable values.

Comment: this is accurate enough for me! http://geography.about.com/library/faq/blqzdistancedegree.htm

Answer (score 0):

In a degree of latitude, there is about 69 miles. Looking at longitude, there is about 49 miles per degree. When i am trying to calculate distance between NYC and LONDON right number is 49.

Select Round(GLength(GeomFromText('LineString(40.756054 -73.986951,51.5001524 -0.1262362)')))*49;

Comment: No, multiply by 69.172 to get miles.